# Python renaming media files

Tags: python, media, id3

I am using ID3 library to rename my files to the data tag containing the song title to take out the numbers and other crap there is in the file name. Haven't used python in a while. Whoever I am pretty sure this is the code, but i get no output nor my files change name.

```
def rename():
        location = "/media/martinstone/6EA41336A412FFEF/Users/Martin7/Desktop/Music/"
        for files in os.walk(location):
                for mfiles in files[2]:
                        if ".mp3" in mfiles:
                                path = location + mfiles
                                id3info = ID3(path)
                                os.rename(path, id3info['TITLE'])
                                print id3info['TITLE']
rename()
```

Comment: Why don't you try printing out the files list? Also depending on your os, looks like location might be a relative URL, so you need to check it against your working directory.

Comment: It looks like a Windows drive mounted on Linux, and it's an absolute path.

Comment: I have double checked the path with the interpreter console to make sure it's printing the files ending with .mp3. the problem is in the code after that

Answer (score 1):

You can use `songdetails` Python package as an alternative to do this job. [Download and install](https://github.com/Ciantic/songdetails) its dependencies.

This script should do the job.

```
import os, songdetails

location = r'/Users/Mo/Music'
os.chdir(location)

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(location):
    for mp3s in files:
        if mp3s.endswith('.mp3'):
            song = songdetails.scan(mp3s)
            song_name="{}.mp3".format(song.title)
            print ("{} will be renamed to {} ".format (mp3s,song.title))
            os.rename(mp3s, song_name)
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This will rename all the files that end with `.mp3` in the directory specified by `location` and all of its sub-directories.

```
import os


def rename_mp3_files(location):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(location):
        for m_file in files:
            if m_file.endswith('.mp3'):
                old_filepath = os.path.join(root, m_file)
                id3info = ID3(old_filepath)

                new_filename = '{}.mp3'.format(id3info['TITLE'])
                new_filepath = os.path.join(root, new_filename)

                os.rename(old_filepath, new_filepath)

                print id3info['TITLE']


location = "/media/martinstone/6EA41336A412FFEF/Users/Martin7/Desktop/Music/"
rename_mp3_files(location)
```

FYI, there are tools that will do this for you. Not to necessarily discourage you from coding it yourself, but just in case you didn't know :).